# how to save checked check_box_tag after submit, without JS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

I have a view for searching method, if I want to choose some kind of search, I have to check it in the box. How I can to save checked checkbox after submit?

```
search.html.haml
         .panel-heading
            #collapse0.panel-collapse.collapse.in
              %ul.list-group
                %li.list-group-item
                  .checkbox
                    %label
                      = check_box_tag :day
                      Last day
                      .checkbox
                    %label
                      = check_box_tag :week
                      Last week
                      .checkbox
                    %label
                      = check_box_tag :mounth
                      Last mounth
                %li.list-group-item
                  .checkbox
                    %label
                      = check_box_tag :post
                      All
                %li.list-group-item
                  .checkbox
                    %label
                      = check_box_tag :genre
                      Genre
```